# How to access external camera connected to a tablet UWP

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, uwp

I have a external usb camera attached to a tablet which has both front and back camera.

Currently I'm using

```
var cameraDevice = await FindCameraDeviceByPanelAsync(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back);
```

To access the back camera, but I would like to access the external usb camera. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find this device using this

```
var videoDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);
```

Then you can take the ID and pass through the MediaCapture class with the InitializeAsync

```
MediaCapture m = new MediaCapture();
await m.InitializeAsync(new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings {  VideoDeviceId = videoDevices.First().Id })
```

Comment: This still only shows me the builtin camera. Not the one connected via USB.

Comment: I have also tried finding the camera using DeviceClass.All and then using the external cameras ID setting up the MediaCapture. But it still did not work unfortunately.